# Sorting algorithm to keep doubleheaders back-to-back

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, constraints

In the context of sports scheduling I have a list of games where teams play more than 1x game, potentially. If that's the case, their games should be back-to-back. Since this is possibly not feasable due to the very nature of pairings, at least they should be as close together as possible.

This is an example of initial pairings where each team plays 2x:

```
[('t05', 't09'), ('t07', 't03'), ('t01', 't09'), ('t03', 't01'), ('t07', 't05'), ('t02', 't06'), ('t04', 't06'), ('t10', 't08'), ('t10', 't04'), ('t08', 't02')]
```

Note that this is not a double round-robin configuration where every team plays every other twice in a home and away game. This is simply a configuration where teams play two games.

I am trying to implement an algorithm to sort these games to keep every team's games as close together as possible. This is the first, simple approach:

```
matches = list(matches)
c = collections.Counter([t for m in matches for t in m.teams])
for t, n in c.iteritems():
    if n > 1:
        # matches containing the team t
        indices = [i for i, m in enumerate(matches) if t in m.teams]
        for i in indices:
            # bring these matches to the front
            matches.insert(0, matches.pop(i))
return matches
```

This is the result:

```
[('t10', 't04'), ('t10', 't08'), ('t01', 't09'), ('t05', 't09'), ('t08', 't02'), ('t07', 't03'), ('t07', 't05'), ('t02', 't06'), ('t04', 't06'), ('t03', 't01')]
```

Obviously it's not very good, as it's one sided and it benefits more the teams at the end of the list by placing their games at the front of the list. With one-sided I mean it looks at just one team in each game and works the sorting for that team, disregarding the second team, which will break the back-to-back balance for that other team.

This would be a perfect case of a maximization using constraint programming, for example using [python-constraint](https://pypi.org/project/python-constraint/) or [pyomo](http://www.pyomo.org/). But I am really bad at modelling constraint satisfaction problems (CSP) so I wouldn't have a clue of where to start with this case.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give us the output you home for from that input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive function can try various orderings in a dynamic programming fashion that  prioritizes connected games over breaks in the sequence.

This one is not particularly optimized but should work quick enough for small lists of games:

```
def gameOrder(games,prevGame=None):
    if len(games)==1: return games    # base condition (only one game)
    best,breaks = games,len(games)-1  # track best order and number of breaks
    for strict in (1,0):              # prioritize connections over breaks
        for i,game in enumerate(games): # each game as 1st in sequence
            if breaks <= strict: return best  # minimum breaks reached
            if strict and prevGame and prevGame.isdisjoint(game): 
                continue # does not connect to previous (strict)
            seq = [game]+gameOrder(games[:i]+games[i+1:],set(game)) # sort rest
            brk = sum(set(g1).isdisjoint(g2) for g1,g2 in zip(seq,seq[1:]))
            if brk < breaks:
                breaks,best = brk,seq # track best so far
    return best # return best found
```

Output:

```
games = [('t05', 't09'), ('t07', 't03'), ('t01', 't09'), ('t03', 't01'), 
         ('t07', 't05'), ('t02', 't06'), ('t04', 't06'), ('t10', 't08'), 
         ('t10', 't04'), ('t08', 't02')]

print(gameOrder(games)) # only one break between (t07,t05) and (t02,t06)
[('t05', 't09'), ('t01', 't09'), ('t03', 't01'), ('t07', 't03'), 
 ('t07', 't05'), ('t02', 't06'), ('t04', 't06'), ('t10', 't04'), 
 ('t10', 't08'), ('t08', 't02')]
```

*Note that this ensures that as many teams as possible have consecutive games. It may not be the best solution if your goal is to minimize the worst case 'distance' between games for any teams, or minimize the average game distance per team.*

Comment: That's a really impressive take, thanks! I wonder if I could modify it so that if a connection can't happen and a break happens no matter what, next it could try to keep the games as close together as possible before "giving up" and leaving it in whatever position they end up being in. Essentially "minimizing" the breaks by keeping those games closer together.

Comment: Yes it is possible. You would have to use a tuple as the measurement of "best". The tuple would use count of breaks as it's first (main) component and you could compute the total (or average) distance from the previous game's teams as the second component).  The `if brk < breaks:` condition would use these tuples instead of a single integer.  Note that the 'minimum breaks reached' optimization would also need to be revised.

Comment: Does this look good? https://gist.github.com/kpagcha/91f136b9925157b5f6fb30db1ee1cb9d I'm trying to think how the base condition should be changed, otherwise it will stop looking at "closer" games when nim breaks is reached. We want it to keep working a bit harder. Maybe comparing with the initial distance value until a "good enough" improvement threshold has been reached? (e.g. distance has been halved) But what if it's not feasable and it takes too long? We wouldn't want that.

Comment: The condition should be `if (brk,dst) <= (breaks,distance):` so that the distance is only taken into consideration when brk and breaks are equal.  (i.e. tuple comparisons).  Also the `if breaks <= strict: break` condition/optimization needs to be revised because it will prevent best distance selection when there is only one break.

Comment: Didn't know about tuple comparison! Right, that's what I meant about the break condition. Should it just keep searching for 0 breaks whether strict or not?

Comment: Given that distance improvements can still be obtained even when strict, I would suggest doing only one pass (i.e. no strict/unstrict) and break the loop only when the result cannot be improved (i.e. breaks==0 or distance<x) where x is a threshold that you can decide depending on the performance you're looking for.

Comment: Well but breaking at `breaks == 0` doesn't mean that the distance can't be optimized anymore does it? There will still be teams whose games are far apart because a "connection" only takes account 1 team, but a game is made up of 2.

Comment: When breaks is zero, you have a complete loop, so one of the teams of the first game will be the unmatched team of the last game.  All zero-break chains will have this characteristic sot there is no possible improvement from having a different team at each end..